# create group objects in loop

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста как быть в таком случае:
    Есть ф-ия(конструктор, возвращающая объект);Как мне создавать объект в цикле присваивая значения новой переменной, при создании объекта
    например:

```
     function createObj(name,gender,age, countP){
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
        this.names = ['jane','alice','Hue','jekky'];
        if(countP){
         for(var i=0; i< countP;i++){
           return createObj(name,gender,countP);
          }
         }
        };
var people1 =createObj('jane', 'female', 26, 320);
/*так создастся один объект, а как мне сделать это в цикле при том присваивая новую переменную с инкрементом (people1,people2... и так до окончания countP, естественно с другими значениями, например берущиеся из массива names) вызов ф-ии выложен для примера на самом деле вызываю, только один раз в цикле, при передаче  параметра countP, в функцию createObj()*/
```

Comment: если у вас массив имен, то создайте массив объектов, зачем вам P-переменных?

Comment: бесконечный вызов `createObj`

Comment: дело в том что условно я не знаю конкретного количества и данных, думаю генерировать их через mathRandom()т.е несколько массивов( имена, пол, возраст, или массивов объектов  точно не знаю).Я не могу написать кучу объектов.Как лучше реализовать это. Условно Планета есть метод заселения людьми собственно добавляя объекты в цикле...думаю идея понятна.

Comment: @АндрейЕлецкий как минимум можно создать один массив `people`  и положить в него все данные (под нужными индексами, при желании)

Comment: допустим у меня выйдет что то на вроде people[{}];но данные то будут генерироваться т.е без сбора в массив это сделать не получится так?
Иными словами я должен создать пустой массив и если  количество людей не равно нулю добавлять в пустой массив объект в дальнейшем обратится people[0] и.т.д

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потенциальное решение исходя из вопроса. На деле лучше не засорять так пространство имен.

**UPD**

```js
var people = [];

function createObj(name, gender, age) {
  var obj = {
    name: name,
    gender: gender,
    age: age
  };
  people.push(obj);
};

Array.prototype.getRandomItem = function() {
  return this[Math.round(Math.random() * (this.length - 1))];
}

var names = ["Sasha", "Vasya", "Tanya", "Petya", "Grisha", "Oleg", "Natasha", "Pasha"];
var gender = ["m", "w"];
var age = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]

for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  createObj(names.getRandomItem(), gender.getRandomItem(), age.getRandomItem());
}

console.log(people);
```

**Через конструктор.**

```js
var people = [];

function createObj(name, gender, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.age = age;
};

Array.prototype.getRandomItem = function() {
  return this[Math.round(Math.random() * (this.length - 1))];
}

var names = ["Sasha", "Vasya", "Tanya", "Petya", "Grisha", "Oleg", "Natasha", "Pasha"];
var gender = ["m", "w"];
var age = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]

for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  var obj = new createObj(
    names.getRandomItem(),
    gender.getRandomItem(),
    age.getRandomItem()
  );

  people.push(obj);
}

console.log(people);
```

Comment: А, как поподробнее, реализовать (учитывая пространство имен).Чтобы не плодить тонну кода?Что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: @АндрейЕлецкий поправил код. Теперь у нас всего одна переменная `people` в `window`.

Comment: так а что делать с динамическими данными т.е они будут попадать аргументами в функцию createObj(), или какую другую но вызывающую её, которые заносятся в массив people, создать еще пустые массивы типа people и генерировать индекс через mathRandom()?

Comment: Вам нужно при вызове `createObj()` занести данные в массив?

Comment: да, они будут методом случайного комбинирования собирать объект увеличивая инкремент

Comment: @АндрейЕлецкий тогда непонятно зачем так усложнять все, когда можно просто записать принятые значения в виде объекта в массив. Взгляни на код еще раз.

Comment: В принципе ответ решает проблему, но не полностью, как быть с масштабированием задачи, хотелось бы в цикле например:
Есть некий массив имен ассоциативный или простой, names["sasha","tanya", "vasya"];
и будет что- то на вроде createObj(names[i], gender[i],age[i]);
i++; или генерируя индекс через mathRandom();
Интересно взглянуть, как вы создадите например 500 объектов с разными свойствами и методами.В этом то и проблема.

Comment: @АндрейЕлецкий так вопрос был совершенно в другом, обновил код))

Comment: ВОООООО.То что нужно.Спасибо.А, конструктор не нужен получается?Вы просто объявляете объект литералом и заполняете его.Расскажите  почему не использовали конструктор объекта.

Comment: @АндрейЕлецкий можно и через конструктор, но вы не использовали ни один метод внутри createObj. Привел второй вариант.